# Count occurrence each shown character in line of text

Tags: c++

How can I count the times the letters in ONLY the given sentence occur? What I've done shows each letter of the alphabet and doesn't even give the correct occurrence

```
void testing()
{
    char temp1[100];

    cout << "\nEnter a line of text: \n";
    cin.getline(temp1, 100);

    vector<int> charCount;
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        charCount.push_back(0);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(temp1); i++)
    {
        char currentChar = tolower(temp1[i]);
        if (isalpha(currentChar))
        {
            charCount[currentChar - 'a'];
        }
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < charCount.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << charCount[i] << static_cast<char>(i + 'a') << endl;
    }
}
```

After some changes it seems to only be displaying the occurrences of the letter (e) which is still not the correct amount..

```
vector<int> charCount;
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    charCount.push_back(0);
}
for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(temp1); i++) {
    char currentChar = tolower(temp1[i]);
    if (isalpha(currentChar)) {
        charCount[currentChar - 'a']++;
    }
    if (charCount[i]) {
        cout << charCount[i] << " " << static_cast<char>(i + 'a') << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: `vector<int> charCount(26);` will create and zero-initialize 26 `int`s in the vector, eliminating the need for the subsequent `for` loop.

Comment: Oh I see how you mean

Comment: Problem is probably a typo: You left out the increment. `charCount[currentChar - 'a'];` -> `charCount[currentChar - 'a']++;`

Comment: @user4581301 how can I limit this to just the letters that occur in the input?

Comment: Place an `if` around the print command. `if (charCount[i])` ought to do it because any number that isn't zero is considered true.

Comment: @user4581301 after removing my second for loop it outputs just a few letters (not necessarily the ones in the sentence)

Comment: No answers to this question yet, so feel free to make a [page-one rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54757993/edit) with your current code and problem.

Comment: When I change the length parameters for my 2nd for loop it displays the correct amount of occurrences but am receiving a runtime error

Comment: Figured it out. My print statement had wrong parameters. Message me if you wanna see how it was done.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own questions if you think the answer will be helpful to others.